# About Face and the demons of Tartaros

Tags: fairy-tail

So one of the goals of Tartaros was

> that they would activate Face, which would then wipe out magic all together from the world. Or at least from the continent, which would be quite helpful for them as they don't use magic, but rather curses.

However, it is clearly stated that the strongest members of Tartaros

> are all demons created by the dark mage Zeref himself. Even if they don't use magic, they are just Zeref's living magic.

Doesn't that make them vulnerable to Face? Wouldn't it kill them?

Comment: That is a good question. Perhaps Zeref's magic would be unaffected by Face. Or maybe they're suicidal. Perhaps their transformation into demons completely disregards their origins in magic. Like Minerva. She was a witch, but now a demon. She would be unaffected, because Face would only affect wizards. But my theory could be invalid, as I'm a couple chapters behind, as of right now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually even if the demons are created by Zeref's magic, they will not die as they are not magic objects but actual living beings. He created these living beings using his Living Magic (Seikatsu Mahou), thus breathing life into them which means they no longer need his magic to continue living. Thus, when all magic will disappear, they will continue to live and their curses won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

They would'nt be affected by the power of FACE , coz' it was clearly stated that ONLY MAGIC which is the Magic User , not them . Their power came from Curse not in Magic . They are planning on a revolution , that would change the world . But that is one of their goal , their main goal is to revive their Master . which is named as E.N.D , the guild master of Tartaros and the strongest demon creation of Zeref . I forgot that chapter where her/he stated that *they will not be affected by the FACE Ability* .

> *The FACE will steal all MAGIC ability from humans and usher in the age
>   of us DEMON - kind .*

Volume 44 - Fairy Tail 371 Tartaros Arc Part 2 - Song of the Heavenly Dragon Page 7
[image]

Comment: Actually we know for a fact that the activation of Face didn't affect only the magic abilities. It affected everything magical, even the magical train or lacryma. http://readms.com/r/fairy_tail/412/2622/12

Comment: But not Tartaros will not be affected coz they are not magical user .

Comment: A lacryma isn't magic user either. It's crystallised magic. And the demons are living magic, Zeref's magic. That's the whole point of my question.

Comment: But your question is will Tartaros be vulnerable about the FACE .

Comment: He means, whether Zeref will be affected by FACE and when Zeref is affected, shouldn't his spells be undone? Like for example if Reedus would make a carriage and if he would lose his magic, would his carriage also disappear?

Comment: Ahhh ..I do get your point . Zeref will not be affected by that "FACE"

Comment: @オレンジ Why not? Isn't Zeref a magician like any other?

Comment: Zeref is a black wizard who use dark magic which opposite to magic used by a wizard . HE who made the END that wanted to revived by the guild tartaros (demon came from the book). It was shown on manga that they will not be affected which is also Zeref will not be affected because he is the one who created them .

Comment: @オレンジ  
Black magic is just a branch of The One Magic. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

As we saw in the manga, what FACE does is to absorb magic power. It's not a dispell or a counter of any type of magic, but instead its ability is to absorb magic power in a radius around each face head.

Now the demons of Zeref are all created by the Living Magic spell, or so it seems, but with the latter addition of the known as Curse Power, which doesn't have a magical nature and it's instead related to something else (humans emotions).

In short, **Zeref's demons may have been created using magic power, but they do not have any magic power inside of them and thus are inmune to FACE effects.**

Comment: Any comments to better improve this answer are welcome! :D